# UITableView under UINavigationBar after popViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

After navigating 3 levels deep using UITableViews under a UINavigationController, finally presenting a UIViewController which calls:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I see this result, which is the UINavigationBar overlayed on top of the UITableView.

[image]

**How do I fix this overlay that only happens after pop'ing the view?**

*Deployment Target 6.0*

I've seen several similar sounding questions, but not exactly this scenario and no answers.

**BTW: using the navigationbar back button does not result in this behavior.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When popping more than one view from the UINavigationController, I've found that view has to completely load, otherwise the UI gets confused and displays oddly. So in my case I added a check and popped the view after load.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {   
    if (self->doPopView) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else {
       // ...
    }
}
```

This approach resolved the UINavigationController vs. UITableView display problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is not unloaded fully hence this strange behavior,are you using the same `UITableViewController`for all drill down. IF it is same ,does it work fine with second level drill down?

Comment: When using segues and navigationbar back button, all ui behaviors are stable and predictable. The behavior in question only happens when I [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Do you make any UIbarButton chanes in viewDidAppear??

Comment: No, I made no changes to any ui components. Just pushing a uitableviewcontroller to a uinavigationcontroller.